# Where I can find the T-SQL Dom generated by the SQL Server ScriptDom parser?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parsing, dom, sql-server-data-tools

I'm playing with the *Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom* library.
I found the way to navigate all the tokens I can get from a TSqlFragment:

```
TSql100Parser parser = new TSql100Parser(false);

TSqlFragment fragment;

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myStream))
{
    fragment = parser.Parse(sr, out parseErrors);
}

foreach (TSqlParserToken token in fragment.ScriptTokenStream)
{
    ...
}
```

I also found the TSqlFragmentVisitor class, so I suppose the ScriptDom library generates a T-SQL DOM from a TSqlFragment that can be navigated. But I can't find the way to do that...

Can you help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is analyze the resultant syntax tree obtained by the parser, you can refer to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arvindsh/archive/2013/04/04/using-the-transactsql-scriptdom-parser-to-get-statement-counts.aspx) link. When you get the root node of your parse tree with `fragment = parser.Parse(sr, out parseErrors)` you can use a visitor to navigate the tree, by extending the `TSqlFragmentVisitor` class as shown in the link. For a complete reference of the classes available with ScriptDom, you can give a look [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I was directed to some projects shared by Gert Drapers in GitHub:

https://github.com/gertd/sqlscriptdom

Here there are an example on how to navigate a fragment throught Visitors.

Regards.